# Analysis in $R^n$

Tags: real-analysis

I have to justify whether this statement is true or false -

If a linear transformation(matrix) $||T||$ is non-invertible then $||T||$ = $0$. $||T||$ is the norm.

Justification -

$||T||$ is = $0$ iff $T$ = $0$, here it's a zero matrix. Now, determinant of a matrix can be zero even if it's not a zero matrix. So, this statement holds for one case and doesn't hold for any other case.

So, is it true or false ?

Comment: Personally, I feel that the linear-algebra tag would be more suitable to your question.

Comment: If  T(x,y)=x, then T is not invertible and has norm 1.

Answer (score 1):

The statement is false because it is not *always true*.

To fully answer the question fully, you should give an *example* of a non-zero matrix that is non-invertible.

Answer (score 0):

You have already answered your question: The norm is zero exactly for the zero operator.

But there are plenty of non-zero non-invertible operators $\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$.

Comment: So, the statement is false?

Comment: @user262860 Yes, it is false.